# Deploy APNS and GCM Services on Amazon AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have requirement to migrate all website content, web-services, database and push notification services (Apple and Google) to Amazon AWS.

I am very much new with this, right now i have hosted all services on "GoDaddy" server - I have checked Amazon document for configuration - still I have few query regarding Push Notification.

**Question:**
 We have developed Apple and Google Push Notification services (in php), now we are planning to migrate to Amazon AWS and my query is

- Do we need to use Amazon SNS service to add push notification support?
- Is Amazon SNS use is mandatory?
- Can we just deploy current push notification services (developed in php) to Amazon AWS server and send push notification?

Any pointer or help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you already have the majority of your app's core functionality running fine, you can move that to AWS EC2 directly. I guess there would be direct calls to the Apple & Google Push API calls. You can do this in the interest of the faster migration process.

But however you can modify your existing logic to use Amazon-SNS and leverage your app for say further expansion like Windows Push, Andorid Push with Baidu etc. with very less impact on your code / app.

Also by making Amazon-SNS do the push messages on your behalf, you are making your app a non-monolithic and going forward it would be helping you to be in the direct of scaling out more instances as well.

Comment: Thank you Naveen for reply and more info, 

1) What I understood is "Right now I can transfer/migrate existing Apple and Google Push Notification services (which i have developed using php), all i need to do is upload existing services on Amazon AWS instance - right?

2) Later on i will check Amazon SNS stuff, there is no mandatory requirement to use Amazon SNS - right?

Comment: Exactly the point, perfect. Kindly look into the SNS stuff, you wont regret once you have deployed your code base. Might be you can target it for next release.

Comment: Thank You.

1) I will deploy current push notification service on Amazon AWS and later on will use SNS.

Comment: Hello Naveen, Do you know how to deploy existing "MySql" database on "Amazon AWS" server.

Comment: That is a very open ended question, you can run MySQL in either EC2 or as RDS. Either way it is a MySQL internally so all the basic MySQL Transfer utilities work the same in AWS EC2 or RDS.

Comment: Ohh yes, sorry for basic questions - was in development field and my key domain is Andriod and iOS, anyway no excuse and thank you. Now can i install MySql tools on EC2 or i need to use command prompt. (I have installed MySql on EC2 instance but looking for some sort of tool, i have also tried RDS little bit but looks like it creates separate instance)